# [react]: Intuitively Transclude another Component

Tags: reactjs, antd

Say I have a component Parent

```
<Parent>
  <Component1 prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2}/>
  <Component2 prop3={prop3} />
</Parent>
```

Normally, passing prop1,2, and 3 would render a perfectly usable Parent component. However, I want this component to be just as intuitive and dynamic like the components in ui libraries (for example, antd does this).

I would like to give the developer the option of transcluding his own component1. His usage would look a little like this:

```
<Parent prop3={prop3}>
  <Component1>
    <div> {prop1} </div>
    <div> {prop2} </div>
  </Component1>
</Parent>
```

So my questions are:

- How would I allow possible? transclusion of a specific component on my component?
- is this okay(not necessarily good, but practical) practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is perfectly fine to do so if that's what you want for your API. It is also pretty simple.

To achieve this you need to use `props.children`. It will then include whatever is in between the opening and closing tag of the component:

In your example, then render function of `Component` would be:

```
render() {
  return <div className="outer-shell">
   {this.props.children}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is allow Component1 to be transcluded, but also allow a default Component1 there by setting in props. It would only render a transcluded Component1 if the developer declares it, otherwise a default is laid out.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you update your question with more details ?

Comment: ```<component prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} prop3={prop3}>```

or


```<component prop2={prop2} prop3={prop3}>
  <child1> {prop1} </child1>
</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent component as a container which can hold other components.

```
class Parent extends Component{

render(){
return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
}
}
```

And this can be used like,

```
class SomeComponent{

render(){

return <Parent><Child1/><Child2></Parent>
}
}
```

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful